# Bind Angular 4 contenteditable div input to HTML output

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to take the user input and render the HTML equivalent inside a contenteditable div element dynamically.

This seems to work only when the input comes from , and not from the div content itself, and that causes bad experience as you'll have to write somewhere, and preview somewhere else.

As for my attempt to use the own div's text and render the HTML on the fly, I faced problems with the cursor position returning to the beginning at each key pressed, as well as having only one element render as HTML for an unknown reason. I do not mind another approach , knowing that the most important thing is being able to write HTML tags and have them rendered within the same container.

```
<div [innerHTML]="HTMLvalue" (input)="HTMLvalue=$event.target.innerText" contenteditable="true" >

</div>
```